# Bash quoting issues - escape in execute shell

Tags: bash

I'm trying to perform some manipulation of JSON which is passed to the script as the first argument.

This works directly from the shell:

```
echo '[{"test": "1"}]' | jq -r ".[]"
```

However in a script I'm a bit lost as to how to escape stuff. The following does not work.

```
final=`sh -c 'echo \'$1\' | jq -r ".[]"'`
echo "Final is $final"
```

I am calling the script like this: `./script.sh '[{"test": "test1" }]'`

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `sh -c`? It adds an additional level of parsing, and therefore makes the syntax more confusing. It's best to avoid it if it's not actually needed.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) explains that `\'` is [not a valid way to escape single quotes](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC1003), though `sh -c` should have no part in this solution in the first place

Answer (score 2):

check this out :

```
#!/bin/bash

json=$1
final=$(echo "$json" | jq -r ".[]")
echo "Final is $final"
```

you can call it like this :

```
bash your_script.sh '[{"test": "test1" }]'
```

output

```
Final is {
  "test": "test1"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
set - '[{"test": "1"}]'
final="$(sh -c 'echo "$1" | jq -r ".[]"' _ "$1")"
echo "$final"
# Output
#{
#  "test": "1"
#}
```

Comment: The strange looking `_` argument is just a placeholder that `sh` consumes as `$0` leaving the "outer" shell's `$1` parameter to be taken as the "inner" shell's `$1` as well

Comment: @glennjackman Indeed, all that trick is to keep OP's `sh -c ...` and give an example of how to do quoting.

Comment: The outermost quotes aren't needed in the assignment.

Comment: @choroba Agreed, but it doesn't do any harm. In general, it's good practice to put `""` around `$(...)`

Answer (score 1):

No need to invoke `sh`.

```
final=`echo "$1" | jq -r ".[]"`
```

Or, if bashisms are allowed:

```
final=`jq -r ".[]" <<< "$1"`
```

Also, consider using `$(...)` instead of `` `...` ``. They nest better.